# Change spinner's selected item color from xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-appcompat

How can I get this spinner's text and bottom arrow icon in white ?

[image]

I want to change the "+47" text color. `popupTheme` xml property with `@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark` change only the text color in the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

**Used this Theme**

**Set to Your Main Application Theme**

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>



</style>
```

---

**PopupMenu**

```
  <style name="PopupMenu" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/yourcolor</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
 </style>
```